# Issue changing from MySQL to MySQLi and mysqli_fetch_array syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to change old `mysql` code to `mysqli`.  I am new to both and do not see what the problem is with my `mysqli_fetch_array` statement.

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_result`, string given

```
session_start(); // start session cookies

include("includes/vars.php");
include("includes/functions.php");
//default values for variables.
$logged_status ='';
$username = '';
$msg = '';
$co='';
$result='';

      $mycon=mysqli_connect("localhost","REDACTED","REDACTED","reinvest_auctions");

    if(isset($_REQUEST['co'])){
        $co=$_REQUEST['co'];
  }

 //Checks if there is a login cookie
  if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])){
   $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
   $_SESSION['password'] = $_COOKIE['password'];
 }
 //if  sessions set, call Db to check pwd
 if(isset($_SESSION['password']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){

 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 $password = $_SESSION['password'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE c_email = $username";
 $check = mysqli_query($mycon, $sql);


 while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
    if ($password != stripslashes($info['c_password']))
      {
        clear();
    }
  else
  {
     redirect('home.php?co='.$co.'');
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your query would have failed so you won't be able to fetch. `$result` is set to an empty string though so that is your current issue. `SELECT * FROM \`members\` WHERE c_email = $username` is invalid, asssuming `$username` is a string. You also are open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries with `mysqli`s prepared statements.

Comment: `$info = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`  need to  be `$info = mysqli_fetch_array($check);`

Comment: @Anant query is invalid too. `$username` needs to be quoted.

Comment: `c_email` must be a text column so you need single quotes around the variable like this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM \`members\` WHERE c_email = '$username' ";`

Comment: @chris85  yes right. sorry my bad

Comment: No usernames and passwords in SO questions, please.  You should change that password on your data base now.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Thank you @Chris85.   I had it coded with mysqli_fetch_array($check) and changed it because of the error, which was as you indicated caused by not having the $username in single quotes.